# Massive map performance (java)

Tags: java, performance, maps

I'm working on a project that requires that I store (potentially) millions of key-value mapping, and make (potentially) the 100s of queries a second. There are some checks I can do around the data I'm working with, but it will only reduce the load by a bit. In addition, I will be making (potentially) 100s of put/removes a second, so my question is: Is there a map sufficient for this task? Is there any way I might optimize the map? Is there something faster that would work for storing key-value mappings?

Some additional information;
- The key will be a point in 3d spaces, I feel like this means I could use arrays, but the arrays would have to be massive
- The value must be an object

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Strongly recommend using an external database (SQL or NoSQL) of some sort. Hundreds of reads and writes per second is not that much, but millions of entries with lots of writes is going to lead to lots of GC pain if you try to keep it all in 1 JVM. And what happens when that JVM dies?

Comment: I don't want to talk about what happens when the JVM dies... (All that data is serialized and saved). I'll look into SQL

Comment: HBase, memcached, redis, etc. – pretty much any of those should work reasonably well based on your needs described so far.

Answer (score 0):

Back of envelope estimates help in getting to terms with this sort of thing. If you have millions of entries in a map, lets say 32M, and a key is a 3d point (so 3 ints->3*4B->12 bytes) ->12B * 32M = 324MB. You didn't mention the size of the value but assuming you have a similarly sized value lets double that figure. This is Java, so assuming a 64bit platform with Compressed OOPs which is default and what most people are on, you pay an extra 12B of object header per Object. So: 32M * 2 * 24B = 1536MB.

Now if you use a HashMap each entry requires an extra HashMap.Node, in Java8 on the platform above you are looking at 32B per Node (use OpenJDK JOL to find out object sizes). Which brings us to 2560MB. Also throw in the cost of the HashMap array, with 32M entries you are looking at a table with 64M entries (because the array size is a power of 2 and you need some slack beyond your entries), so that's an extra 256MB. All together lets round it up to 3GB?

Most servers these days have quite large amounts of memory (10s to 100s of GB) and adding an extra 3GB to the JVM live set should not scare you. You might consider it disappointing that the overhead exceeds the data in your case, but this is not your emotional well being, it's a question of will it work ;-)

Now that you've loaded up the data, you are mutating it at a rate of 100s of inserts/deletes per second, lets say 1024, reusing above quantities we can sum it up with: 1024 * (24*2 + 32) = 70KB. Churning 70KB of garbage per second is small change for many applications, and not something you necessarily need to sweat about. To put it in context, a JVM will contend with collecting many 100s of MB of Young Generation in a matter of 10s of milliseconds these days.

So, in summary, if all you need is to load the data and query/mutate it along the lines you describe you might just find that a modern server can easily contend with a vanilla solution. I'd recommend you give that a go, maybe prototype with some representative data set, and see how it works out. If you have an issue you can always find more exotic/efficient solutions.

Comment: If mutation is that frequent, a simple HashMap with a global lock is probably going to kill performance.  ConcurrentHashMap or something similar is most likely called for.

Comment: @jtahlborn OP mentioned nothing about concurrent access, so I assumed nothing... 1000 ops/sec is not a problem even for standard RW lock. CHM has a very large footprint overhead, you might be better off with Cliff Clicks lock free map.